# Rails 6 - Issue with nested resources in a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

So I am trying to nest resources under a namespace, however when i try to navigate to the UserProfile new page I am hitting the following error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /users/xxxxxx/user_profiles/new
uninitialized constant AccountManagementPages::UserProfilesController
Did you mean?  AccountManagementPages::UsersController
```

This is how the resources are set up in my `routes.rb` file

```
  constraints(AccountManagement) do
    namespace :account_management_pages, path: '' do
      root to: 'users#new', as: :registration
      resources :users, except: %w[index], path_names: { new: 'register' } do
        resources :user_profiles
      end
    end
  end
```

my file structure for both my controller and views are configured correctly (at least I thought they were).

[image: image of controller nesting for namespaced routes]

And here is how my views are nested.

[image: Image of view nesting in relation to controller nesting above]

This is how I have my `user_profiles_controller` configured:

```
module AccountManagementPages
  module Users
    class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController

      def show; end

      def new; end

      def edit; end

      def create; end

      def update; end

    end
  end
end
```

and my model associations (don't think this is overly relevant here but just incase it is.)

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_one :user_profile, dependent: :destroy
end

class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
end

any help here would be greatly appreciated. Not sure why I am hitting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "rake routes | grep account_management_pages" say? Nested routes don't require a nester folder structure. A namespace usually does but that can be managed by specifying a path, a controller, etc.

Comment: @razvans it was the controller.. lol.. i do not know how i overlooked naming the controller in the routes file.. lol.. thanks! Ive been staring at that for far too long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `rails routes`, you'll get (amongst other things):

```
                                 Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                        Controller#Action
          account_management_pages_registration GET    /                                                          account_management_pages/users#new
    account_management_pages_user_user_profiles GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles(.:format)                    account_management_pages/user_profiles#index
                                                POST   /users/:user_id/user_profiles(.:format)                    account_management_pages/user_profiles#create
 new_account_management_pages_user_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/register(.:format)           account_management_pages/user_profiles#new
edit_account_management_pages_user_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id/edit(.:format)           account_management_pages/user_profiles#edit
     account_management_pages_user_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/user_profiles#show
                                                PATCH  /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/user_profiles#update
                                                PUT    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/user_profiles#update
                                                DELETE /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/user_profiles#destroy
                 account_management_pages_users POST   /users(.:format)                                           account_management_pages/users#create
              new_account_management_pages_user GET    /users/register(.:format)                                  account_management_pages/users#new
             edit_account_management_pages_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                  account_management_pages/users#edit
                  account_management_pages_user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#show
                                                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#update
                                                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#update
                                                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#destroy
```

As you can see, `user_profiles` is not nested under the `users` namespace. Rails, therefore, is expecting:

```
module AccountManagementPages
  class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController

    ...

  end
end
```

If you do:

```
constraints(AccountManagement) do
  namespace :account_management_pages, path: '' do
    root to: 'users#new', as: :registration
    resources :users, except: %w[index], path_names: { new: 'register' } do
      scope module: :users do 
        resources :user_profiles
      end
    end
  end
end
```

...and then `rails routes`, you get (amongst other things):

```
                                         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                Controller#Action
          account_management_pages_registration GET    /                                                          account_management_pages/users#new
    account_management_pages_user_user_profiles GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles(.:format)                    account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#index
                                                POST   /users/:user_id/user_profiles(.:format)                    account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#create
 new_account_management_pages_user_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/register(.:format)           account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#new
edit_account_management_pages_user_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id/edit(.:format)           account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#edit
     account_management_pages_user_user_profile GET    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#show
                                                PATCH  /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#update
                                                PUT    /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#update
                                                DELETE /users/:user_id/user_profiles/:id(.:format)                account_management_pages/users/user_profiles#destroy
                 account_management_pages_users POST   /users(.:format)                                           account_management_pages/users#create
              new_account_management_pages_user GET    /users/register(.:format)                                  account_management_pages/users#new
             edit_account_management_pages_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                  account_management_pages/users#edit
                  account_management_pages_user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#show
                                                PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#update
                                                PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#update
                                                DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                       account_management_pages/users#destroy
```

...and `user_profiles` will be nested under `users`. And you should be able to use:

```
module AccountManagementPages
  module Users
    class UserProfilesController < ApplicationController

      ...

    end
  end
end
```